# How can I submit a form to a particular URL in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I want to submit a form using jQuery and store the form values in a database. For this I have written this code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="login_err" style="color:#FF0000; text-align: center; padding: 10px;"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Name :</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            <span id="name_error"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Email :</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            <span id="email_error"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Telephone :</label>
            <input type="text" name="tele" id="tele" />
            <span id="tele_error"></span>
        <li>
        <li>
            <label>Message :</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" /></textarea>
            <span id="message_error"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
           <label>How did you hear about us?</label>
           <select name="soption" id="soption">
               <option selected='selected'></option>
               <option>I am a repeat customer<option>
               <option>You are recommended to me<option>
               <option>Google Search<option>
               <option>Travelzoo<option>
               <option>News paper artical<option>
               <option>Facebook<option>
               <option>twitter<option>
           </select>
           <span id="soption_error"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="form_submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

```js
$('#form_submit').click(function(){
    var name1 = $('#name').val();
    var email1 = $('#email').val();
    var tele1 = $('#tele').val();
    var message1  = $('#message').val();
    var soption1 = $('#soption').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/test/index.php/test_con/form',
        data: 'name=' + name1 + '&email=' + email1 + '&tele=' + tele1 + '&message=' + message + '&soption=' + soption1,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#login_err').html('Success ...');
            $('#form_submit').attr('action', "www.google.com").submit(); 
        });
    }
```

This is the way I am storing database values but when I submit the form those values are going to a particulate link like 'www.google.com' but it's not working properly i am getting like this 'http://localhost/test/index.php/test_con/www.google.com'.

Answer (score 3):

As you're submitting the form via AJAX you need to stop the standard form submission event. You can do this by using `preventDefault()`:

```
$('#form_submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // the rest of your code here...
});
```

You also should remove the line that changes the `form` action - this is counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

remove the line where you have set the action in success function of ajax i.e.

```
$('#form_submit').attr('action', "www.google.com").submit();
```